# "Little girl and maximum XOR"

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, xor

How do i solve [this](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/276/D) problem on codeforces.

The second approach (Non DP) in the [Editorial](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/6779) seems easier but i am unable to understand how it works.

Can somebody explain the non dp approach in detail?

Also i found this code implementation which i'm unable to understand

```
#include <iostream>
#define ll long long
#define cnt_leading_zero_bits(x) __builtin_clzll(x);

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ll l, r;
    cin >> l >> r;
    if (l == r) {
        cout << "0\n";
        return 0;
    }
    ll cnt = cnt_leading_zero_bits(l ^ r);
    ll val = 64 - cnt;
    cout<< ((1LL << val) - 1) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Somebody help.

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: The code mentioned isn't another question. It is the implementation of the above mentioned editorial which I'm unable to understand.

Comment: Question 1: "Can somebody explain the non dp approach in detail?", Question 2: Somebody help me to understand how this code implementation works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read about `__builtin_clzll` in http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

> — Built-in Function: `int __builtin_clzll (unsigned long long x)`
>
> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined.

From https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29510,

> The maximum possible XOR of any two integers from an interval `[l, r]` can be determined from `l ⊕ r`, assuming `l, r` to be integers. This value is equal to `pow(2, p) − 1`, where `p` is the smallest value such that `pow(2, p)` is larger than `l ⊕ r`.

Now, relating with the code,

```
val = 64 - __builtin_clzll(l ^ r);    // p

(1LL << val) - 1;    // pow(2, p) - 1
```

Comment: I'm unable to understand how this code works for solving the mentioned problem.